# django rest framework OAuth2 Toolkit

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, oauth2-toolkit

i use django rest framework and OAuth2 Toolkit in my django backend app. I registered users in django admin site. Whne i try to get access token with CURL for user i get error:

```
{"error":"invalid client"}.
```

my curl request is bellow:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=password&username=myuser&password=mypass" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the right secret and id and/or the right grant-type?

1) Go to `<yoursite>/admin` and login with your admin account

2) Go to `<yoursite>/o/applications` and choose your application

Now you can see your secret, id and grant type(should be 'password').
Also have a look at the client type(should be 'confidential')

Answer (score 0):

Thank you fo your help I solve my problem. My right curl request is bellow:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD" --user "CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET"
```